# Find and Replace lines with variable

Tags: notepad++, find-replace

There are below 100 cases in a file with different variables (marked in bold) in a log file. I have to find these 4 lines with different variables and import to a new file

Case Eg:

```
CARD INSERTED
Card BIN group is 2
Card BIN entry is INDUSOFFUSUS CARDS
**046337** ATR RECEIVED T=0
```

Comment: That's not a job for Notepad++, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: @toto Actually it is, the algorithm I forsee is to turn these 4 lines into 1 line (replacing the \r\n with space), then delete any other lines, then with a nice regexp extract the needed data.

Comment: @Gar: And how to you select the lines to be kept? How do you replace the spaces you have inserted into linebreak to get the block?

Comment: can you please add more data to the example? for me It is not clear what to keep. Also, It is not clear which part of those lines can be variable or not, and what to keep. Finally, what does discarded lines look like? Could you please add a longer example with expected output? Thanks

Comment: @toto replace INSERTED\r\nCard with INSERTED Card  (and do this to the other lines of the bloc) , then  select these lines with a bookmark , inverse the bookmarks, and delete bookmarked lines

Comment: @Gar:You haven't answered my questions. How do you select the lines? How do you revert the spaces into linebreaks?

Comment: @toto I did, once you turn the blocs into lines, you select them with a bookmark (^CARD INSERTED)  , and you do not have to revert the spaces, the OP needs the values inside the line anyway, and with a simple regexp can extract them from the line newly formed

Comment: @Gar: Then answer the question, I'll be glad to give you my vote if you can demonstrate that it works but I think you haven't understood the question, I suggest you to reread it.

Comment: @toto : Oh i fully understood, and did this before , ok , i'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I would follow:

Step 1: Turn the bloc of 4 lines to 1 line, removing the carriage return

replace \r\nCard BIN  with |Card BIN

replace CARDS\r\n**   with CARDS|**

Step 2 : Bookmark all these lines by selecting

CARD INSERTED|Card BIN

Step 3 : reverse the bookmarks selection (from the menu Bookmarks)

Step 4 : deleted all bookmarked lines (from the Bookmarks menu)

At this step , you should have a file with only "interesting" lines

CARD INSERTED|Card BIN group is 2|Card BIN entry is INDUSOFFUSUS CARDS|**046337** ATR RECEIVED T=0

Step 5 : transform these lines to whatever you want  like

regexp replace : ^CARD INSERTED\|Card BIN group is ([^\|]*)\|Card BIN entry is ([^\|]*)\|\*\*([^\*]*)\*\* ATR RECEIVED T=(.*)$

with GROUP:\1;BIN:\2;ATR:\3;T:\4

This shall give lines like 
GROUP:2;BIN:INDUSOFFUSUS CARDS;ATR:046337;T:0

That you can of course customize.